# I'm making a mistake somewhere while making a simple design

Tags: java, android, android-studio

no matter what I do in my design, I want to center what I wrote with the photographs, but I cannot do the design, I wonder where I am going wrong I'm learning new and tried to make a design like in the photo
I'll create the rest using the recycler view and card view
Enough explanation, I hope I don't want to confuse you

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:contentDescription="TODO" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="text" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Date" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="text" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve, and what is wrong.

Comment: @Nicolas I want to do the design in the image

Comment: Did you try setting the gravity property for the text views to center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitted the center part to two linear layouts. Also added `android:gravity="center|bottom"` to the `TextView` which contains the date.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="text" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="text" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"
            android:text="Date" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp" />
</LinearLayout> </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Here's how it looks like. I added some colors so it's easier to see where layouts begin and end. The colors are not part of the xml.

[image: layout]